# Key Error: 'Date' when plotting a line from index column 'Date'

Tags: pandas, plot, line, timeline

I am trying to plot a rather simple graph in pandas using my first column called "Date" as x axis, but I stumble upon a Key Error and I am at a loss where the issue is. I am using Python 2 under Anaconda distribution.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read file
df=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\sophi\Desktop\ResidentialLoans.csv",index_col='Date')

#extracting the individual components
index=df.index
columns=df.columns
values=df.values

# plot the graph
ax=plt.gca()
df.plot(x='Date', y='LTV < = 75%', kind="line", ax=ax)
df.plot(x='Date', y='LTV Over 75 < = 90%', kind="line", ax=ax, color="red")
plt.show()
```

Here is a screenshot of my dataframeю

Residential Loans data:

[image]

I get the following error message and nothing is plotted:

```
KeyErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-52b0be68296d> in <module>()
      1 # plot the graph
      2 ax=plt.gca()
----> 3 df.plot(x='Date', y='LTV < = 75%', kind="line", ax=ax)
      4 df.plot(x='Date', y='LTV Over 75 < = 90%', kind="line", ax=ax, color="red")
      5 plt.show()

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.pyc in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2939                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   2940                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2941                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   2942     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   2943 

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.pyc in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   1975                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1976                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 1977                  **kwds)
   1978 
   1979 

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.pyc in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1764                 if is_integer(x) and not data.columns.holds_integer():
   1765                     x = data_cols[x]
-> 1766                 elif not isinstance(data[x], ABCSeries):
   1767                     raise ValueError("x must be a label or position")
   1768                 data = data.set_index(x)

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
   2683             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2684         else:
-> 2685             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2686 
   2687     def _getitem_column(self, key):

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2690         # get column
   2691         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2692             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2693 
   2694         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   2484         res = cache.get(item)
   2485         if res is None:
-> 2486             values = self._data.get(item)
   2487             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   2488             cache[item] = res

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.pyc in get(self, item, fastpath)
   4113 
   4114             if not isna(item):
-> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   4116             else:
   4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

C:\Users\sophi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.pyc in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3063                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   3064             except KeyError:
-> 3065                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   3066 
   3067         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Date'
```

Comment: Once you set the index to `Date`, it is no longer a named column and cannot be passed as the argument for `x`. I believe if the value you want as the `x` is the index already, you can just omit it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [pandas docs on `plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

> **x** *: label or position, default None*
>   ...
>   **use_index** *: boolean, default True*
>   Use index as ticks for x axis

From this you can infer that the dataframe index is the default for the x-axis. So you don't need to pass the index name into `plot()` as `plot(x=...)`; you can just remove that argument and call it with `plot(y='column name', ...)` since the column you want to use is the index.

The reason you're getting the error is because once you set a column as the index, it is no longer a column in your dataframe that you can access by name.

Specifically, this means that you cannot use `df.__getitem__(index_name)` or `df[index_name]` at all---you will see the same errors if you tried to access `df['Date']`. If you look at your `df.columns` you'll see `Date` isn't in there, and if you access your columns by position using `df.iloc[]`, you'll notice that index 0 is mapped to the `'Single: less than 2.50'` column.

Note that to "restore" the index as a normal column, you can at any time use `df.reset_index()`. This will just number your indices in their current order, and set the index to be a regular column and you can reference it by name again. This is the inverse operation to the `df.set_index()` function, which your import does by setting `index_col='Date'`.

Comment: Alexander, many thanks! I removed the explicit passing of the index name as x axis name and this solved the problem. Perhaps I have mistakenly followed another post advice on indexing issues.

Comment: I had to learn this the hard way myself, too! No worries! And I had to go searching to find where in the documentation it explicitly says this---it doesn't, just gotta infer it from those descriptions of the arguments :/